# How to get target basename in CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE?

Tags: cmake

I want to add a post link step into the linking command in CMake. E.g. something like:

```
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "${CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE}"
    "postlink <TARGET> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$$(basename <TARGET>).foo")
```

`$$(basename <TARGET>)` is the part that is giving the headache. It does not work. Neither with backticks. `<TARGET_BASE>` gives the filepath without the extension but how to get rid of the directory path? I could work around it by using a wrapper script for the postlink command but it would be quite ugly and I just wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `add_custom_command(TARGET ... POST_BUILD ...)` rather then changing `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE`:

```
function(add_post_processing_to_target _target)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${_target}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "--- postlink $<TARGET_FILE:${_target}>"
        COMMAND postlink $<TARGET_FILE:${_target}> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${_target}.foo
    )
endfunction()
```

---

To answer your original question, try `<TARGET_NAME>`

- See [cmLocalGenerator.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmLocalGenerator.cxx#L680)
- [CMake Useful Variables: Expansion Rules](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) obviously needs some update.

Comment: I cannot use `add_custom_command()` because it will rerun whenever the target binary changes (e.g. when it gets stripped later in the build in our case). But `<TARGET_NAME>` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me to the "documentation".

Comment: @jil You are welcome. But the `add_custom_command(... POST_BUILD ...)` just ends up in a "multi-line instruction" (it doesn't add another target and it does not check for dependencies). More or less the same as modifying `CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE`, just that you can use generator expressions. If you generate makefiles, just give my code a try and see what's actually generated.